# Drupal 7 How to redirect registered user to an external account page?

Tags: drupal

I am new in drupal 7.Is the following scenario possible ?

Assuming I have 3 differents distributions installed on one drupal 7 core for 3 different users group informations.But I want a single login interface for them.This interface will have login, password and group fields (Select list ).When the user post his login, password and select his group, he will be redirected to his home page.

In fact to be clear, it is a multisite drupal with one common database and one common login interface where the user has to select his group or site on the login interface.

Answer (score 0):

There is a hook function named [hook_user_login](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_login/7),which is used to `hook-into` when a user is logged in.If you have a dropdown named `mynewField` ,the value of this field can be obtained from the `$edit` variable.Check the value of your custom field and redirect it using [drupal_goto](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7).Hope this is what u meant mate.. :)

```
function myModule_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
      $my_select_value = $edit['input']['mynewField'];
      if($my_select_value == 1){
        $external_url = 'http://www.example.com';
        drupal_goto($external_url);
      }
 }
```